# Can I use Facebook Graph API for getting information about users, posts, groups?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Now I'm trying to get information about Users, Groups, Posts and I face with messages:

"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22)

Looks like FB API it's impossible to use for this purposes (work with posts/groups/uses)
Am I right?
Or how to avoid this problem?
If most of FB API Methods are restricted, which of them still can be used?

Comment: You don't just automatically get access to everything, people need to grant your app access.